# Adding criteria to VBA copy and paste

Tags: vba

I have the following code that works but I need to add another criteria to it.  The criteria I need to add is a wildcard search for **`*Utilities`**.  So if column L has the word **`utilities`**, then include the row in the copy and paste.  If not, do not copy and paste.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim Cl As Range
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim SrcSht As Worksheet
Dim DestSht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open("Transactional Activity PD 10-2017 (Expense 
Accounts).xlsb")
Set SrcSht = SrcWbk.Sheets("Activity")
Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transactions")

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Cl In DestSht.Range("AE2", DestSht.Range("AE" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then .Add Cl.Value, Nothing
    Next Cl
    For Each Cl In SrcSht.Range("AE2", SrcSht.Range("AE" & 
Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(Cl.Value) And Cl.Offset(, -29).Value = "PV" And 
Cl.Offset(, -15) Like "*Utilities" Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
                Set Rng = Cl
            Else
                Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cl)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cl
End With
Rng.EntireRow.Copy DestSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

THANKS!

Comment: You need to go a step further, and show  what you tried and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok.  I amended with my trial, which returns an error each time. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: why did you split some of the program lines ?    it produces invalid code

Answer (score 0):

The following adds a criteria of only including rows where "utilities" is found in column L of the same row as the test being performed on column AE. Not tested.

```
Dim Cl As Range
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim SrcSht As Worksheet
Dim DestSht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open("Transactional Activity PD 10-2017 (Expense Accounts).xlsb")
Set SrcSht = SrcWbk.Sheets("Activity")
Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transactions")

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each Cl In DestSht.Range("AE2", DestSht.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Not .exists(Cl.Value) Then .Add Cl.Value, Nothing
    Next Cl

    For Each Cl In SrcSht.Range("AE2", SrcSht.Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If Not .exists(Cl.Value) And Cl.Offset(, -29).Value = "PV" And _
        InStr(Cl.Offset(, -19), "utilities") > 0 Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
                Set Rng = Cl
            Else
                Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cl)
            End If
        End If

    Next Cl

End With

Rng.EntireRow.Copy DestSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this one, but get an error for this part: If Not .exists(Cl.Value) And Cl.Offset(, -29).Value = "PV" And _
        InStr(Cl.Offset, -25), "utilities") >0 Then

Comment: Edited. Typo, should have read  InStr(Cl.Offset(, -19), "utilities") > 0